# How to call librsync anyway?

Tags: compilation, centos, diff, librsync

I'm trying to understand how to get [librsync](http://librsync.sourcefrog.net/doc/librsync.html) to work (ie. make signature/make delta/patch) under CENTOS 5.8 x86_64 standard (before I eventually try to compile it under windows), but since I'm mainly a Windows/Delphi guy, and given the lack of documentation, I'm having trouble running it.

Can someone tell me how to call librsync? I followed [the intructions](https://github.com/kaseya/librsync) to compile it, which is basically:

```
  $ ./configure
  $ make all check
```

According the echoed output, it worked. I realize it's a library rather than a executable, so now I'm lost: how can I call librsync anyway?

As far as I can see, compiling librsync also resulted in generating an executable called **rdiff**, I tried calling it under putty, but it won't work either!

Comment: What does "won't work" mean anyhow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to make a .c, compile it and link it to librsync.la (using a command such as gcc -o myprogram myprogram.o librsync.la)

Your .c program will include the librsync.h, and call the rs_??? functions that you need.

The `rdiff.c` file in the distribution seems to be a good sample. See the `Makefile` for the commands to run to compile your program (search for `rdiff` inside it).